# Extract value from __NSArrayM

Tags: swift, nsarray

I have printed the value that I want to get and is like this:

```
a =  Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x1704494b0>(9))
```

How can I extract the value 9?
I wrote this but is wrong: `let a = (parseJSON[index] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "subjects_count")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:-

```
guard let a = (parseJSON[index] as AnyObject).object(forKey: "subjects_count"), let value = a.first else {return}
let stringValue = String(value)
print(stringValue)
```

Comment: And how can I cast it to String?

Comment: I have modified the code including type casting to string

Comment: Glad it helps:)

Answer (score 0):

Use Swift native types and key / index subscription

```
if let dict = parseJSON[index] as? [String:Any],
   let subjectsCount = dict["subjects_count"] as? [Int], !subjectsCount.isEmpty {
   print(subjectsCount[0])
}
```